# Remove Simple ListView Element in android

Tags: android

I am displaying Simple ListView. On long press event, Dialog is displayed to remove that item from ListView. Here is my code:

```
myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listSendEmailFinal);

myList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos, long id) {
        return onLongListItemClick(v,pos,id);
}
protected boolean onLongListItemClick(View v, final int pos, long id) {
        final String str=myList.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
        Log.i("ListView", "onLongListItemClick stirng=" + str);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new  
                AlertDialog.Builder(EmailReceiversActivity.this);
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                       }
                   })
                   .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                       }
                   });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
            return true;
        }

    });
```

When I press 'Yes' Button, that item should be removed from listview.I've used ArrayAdapter. And 'listItems' is a string array

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listItems);
 myList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in click event of yes button Just remove the item from "listItems" and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Thats it..!

Answer (score 4):

Just Try this inside the YES button click:

```
listItems.remove(pos);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Yes I tried this. Actually listItems.remove(pos) is not working for String Array. And should I create new object for ArrayAdapter?

Comment: I have shown you a way, now Whether you are having ArrayList or Array, you can do for removing that particular object

Comment: FYI, ArrayList would be a better option as compared to String Array.

Comment: @KrishnaSuthar its done with this answer, and you accepted others....wow!! Thanx for rewarding back exactly.